# Add mysqli options in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have several fields in my database that are DECIMAL(10,2) or INT values, when I return the results everything is returned as string.

Example:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, operacion_id FROM operaciones";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->getResultArray();

    return $this->response->setStatusCode(200)
                    ->setContentType('application/json')
                    ->setJSON($result);
```

And that returns:

```
[{
    "id": "31",
    "operacion_id": "ES-2021-0031"
},
{
    "id": "30",
    "operacion_id": "ES-2021-0030"
}]
```

I tried to put directly in system\Database\MySQLi\Connection.php connect() method:

```
$this->mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
```

This works well but I know that it is not upgrade safe.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report or feature request. Please consider to report the issue to the actual project, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: What would you consider upgrade safe? And what did prevent you so far to do this upgrade safe? (just asking for more context, no trick question)

Comment: Hi! Dharman's answer below is correct. When I said not upgradable safe basicly is due I was modifying core files, so if I upgrade Codeigniter version this changes would be overwriten. Thank you!

Comment: IMHO this should be (made) possible in the database configuration already, as otherwise as you write updating the driver would remove it (e.g. when applying security or other updates ). It's years since I've used code-igniter, is it perhaps possible to put somewhere {in the configuration](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)?

Comment: I've quickly looked into Codeigniter 4 and it appears to me that the Mysqli driver does not support this option in its configuration. As _Dharman_ mentions using prepared statements can circumvent that db driver inability. You need to say thought if it is possible to use prepared statements with Codeigniter and the (default) Mysqli driver. Next to that I would suggest to file a feature request  that the driver supports this option (it looks reasonable to me to have such an option supported with mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply this option to `mysqli` property of your database object.

```
// run this after your DB connection has been initialized
$this->db->mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
// and then run your queries
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

When working with prepared statements, you don't have to apply this setting as prepared statements always return the data in the correct type.